# How to escape parenthesis for the cp command inside a Makefile

Tags: bash, makefile

I have this Makefile:

```
VAR=foo(1).txt foo(2).txt
foobar: $VAR
    cp -p $^ foo/
```

When I run it I get this error:

```
$ make test
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: `cp -p foo(1).txt foo(2).txt foo/'
Makefile:3: recipe for target 'foobar' failed
make: *** [test] Error 1
```

How to quickly get rid of it?

Comment: Same way you escape anything? `cp foo\(1\).txt foo\(2\).txt out` or `cp "foo(1).txt" "foo(2).txt" out`...

Comment: change the names to not have parens in them

Comment: @JarrodRoberson Good point but I cannot change these names :(

Comment: @Kevin I already tried to use `| perl -p -e 's/([() ])/\\$1/g'` but it doesn't work :(

Comment: That is a completely different question.

Comment: @Kevin Yes an I am sorry about this. I initially thought of a simple `cp` issue.

Comment: Don't use files named like that with `make`.  Can't you use different names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrapt the file names in double quotes

```
cp "foo(1).txt" "foo(2).txt" /out
```

**Test**

```
$ cp "foo(1).txt" "foo(2).txt" out/
$ ls out/
foo(1).txt  foo(2).txt
```

Or much safer would be

```
cp 'foo(1).txt' 'foo(2).txt' out/
```